# Vuejs Nuxt - how to modifying facebook login button style?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, facebook-login

I'm new at Vuejs and Nuxt. I'm using a library [facebook-login-vuejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/facebook-login-vuejs?fbclid=IwAR37siobOIQ8EPiLQE7rnOxW4BZlgTKNZ_hsraDpMPT5sUmvDQLYoM808o4),
it works but I need little bit modifying like the button width adjustment.
I tried to give a "fbutton" class in this component :

```
<facebook-login
    class="button fbbutton"
    appId="102023513468xxx"
    loginLabel="Facebook"
    @login="fbOnLogin"
    @logout="fbOnLogout"
></facebook-login>
```

and here my CSS :

```
.fbbutton button{
 width: 100px;}
```

But nothing gonna change

[here in this picture, the width doesn't change. Seems like set by facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCMwW.png)

[this one also, the button still out of the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GFjH.png)

Please any body can help me how to solve this, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Checking [the facebook-login-vuejs source code](https://github.com/iliran11/facebook-login-vue/blob/master/src/facebook-login.vue) you clearly see "the html structure".

You need to override the "default" css rule.

```
.facebook-login button {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 34px;
  min-width: 225px;
  padding: 0 15px 0px 46px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4c69ba, #3b55a0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks lot, it's helpful . I can now even create my own button and style it as I like

Comment:   css rulez!